# How to run multiple celery workers?

Tags: python, flask, celery

I have two tasks in python which want to run them in background by celery. 
I use the following functions to define the celery.

```
from celery import Celery
def make_celery(app):
    celery = Celery(
        app.import_name,
        backend=app.config['CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND'],
        broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL']
    )
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    class ContextTask(celery.Task):
        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return self.run(*args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


flask_app = Flask(__name__)
flask_app.config.update(
    CELERY_BROKER_URL='redis://localhost:6379/0',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='redis://localhost:6379/0'
)
celery = make_celery(flask_app)



####task 1
@celery.task(name="run1")
def code1(a, b):
    return a * b

####task 2
@celery.task(name="run2")
  def code2(c, d):
      return c + d

 code1.delay(5, 8)
 code2.delay(77, 26)
```

I run the celery workers as following:

```
celery -A run1.celery worker&
celery -A run2.celery worker&
```

But when I send some jobs to the background I face with the errors below:

""Received unregistered task of type 'run1'.
The message has been ignored and discarded.
Did you remember to import the module containing this task?
Or maybe you're using relative imports?""

When I run only one of the celery workers, it works without any error - but when run multiple celery workers I face with this error.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm way late to this party, but maybe this can help someone else.

The proper way to start a celery worker:

```bash
celery -A <filename containing celery object>:<celery object> worker
```

A standard invocation is:

```bash
celery -A tasks:celery worker
```

Where `tasks.py` contains the functions and celery object. Celery will pickup each task/function in the file automatically.